# I am trying to get the current CurrentPageReference on button click from object ,but it is keep taking a old record id

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I am trying to get the current CurrentPageReference on button click from object ,but it is keep taking a old record id from cache after the refresh only it is taking the current record ID

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from "lwc";
import { CurrentPageReference } from "lightning/navigation";
import getGradeSettingCounts from "@salesforce/apex/GradeDistrubutionController.getGradeSettingCounts";

export default class GradeDistribution extends LightningElement {
  fieldId = "";

  @wire(CurrentPageReference)
  async receivePageReference(result) {
    this.fieldId = result.state.c__recordId;
    if (result.state.c__recordId) {
      await this.gradeMod();
    }
  }

  @track gradeModeration = [];
  gradeSetting = "";
  statistics = "";

  async gradeMod() {
    const grade = await getGradeSettingCounts({
      recordId: this.fieldId
    });
    const statistucsResult = this.getStatistics(grade.enrolments);
    this.statistics = statistucsResult;

    this.gradeSetting = grade;
    const gradeCounts = {};

    grade.enrolments.forEach((item) => {
      const letterGrade = item.Letter_Grade__c;
      if (gradeCounts[letterGrade]) {
        gradeCounts[letterGrade]++;
      } else {
        gradeCounts[letterGrade] = 1;
      }
    });

    this.gradeModeration = Object.keys(gradeCounts).map((key) => ({
      key,
      count: gradeCounts[key]
    }));

    this.gradeModeration.sort((a, b) => a.key.localeCompare(b.key));
  }
```